# Solr ElasticSearch with cassandra

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, cassandra

i'm looking for a free solution to use solr or elasticsearch with cassandra(the enterprise search version of datastax is not free)

thanks in advance

Comment: For development purposes, Datastax Enterprise is free.

Comment: i'm looking more for production purpose ?